Is it possible to disable Sorting an Transform on useStortable Items once they are disabled in dnd-kit?
I've been struggling with dnd-kit for a number of days now and although it seems like this would be easy I can't figure out how to achieve what I need.
Basically I'm using a useSortable hook for each item in a sortable list inside of the  and then  components.
As the application runs, items in the list become disabled, when the state changes and we re-render the list using the disabled property of the hook useSortable({id: rowNumber, disabled: disableDnD});
As the app run the list starts to look like this with each item that is been disabled, truns grey.

The problem is that the items which are still active and (and the user should be able to reorder) can be moved in the list over any already disabled item. But the idea is that once the top part of the list is grey out you should not be able to sort or move items into it.
I've been racking my head trying to figure out how to make this possible.}

